# Fatal Error using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I trying to develop a plugin .the plugin was already developed but the guy who developed left us no support has been given.When i am trying activate the following error comes up and its not getting activated.

**Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs..\wp-content\plugins\sjr-product-import\functions.php on line 238**

line number and the associated function is given bellow.
I do not know what could be the problem.

```
/**
* Installation. Runs on activation.
* @since   1.0.0
* @return  void
*/
function install(){

global $wpdb;

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$this->db_table} (
          `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `row_id` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
          `description` text,
          `google_product_category` text,
          `product_type` text,
          `link` text,
          `image_link` text,
          `additional_image_link` text,
          `condition` text,
          `availability` text,
          `price` text,
          `sale_price` text,
          `sale_price_effective_date` text,
          `brand` text,
          `gtin` text,
          `mpn` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `item_group_id` int(22) DEFAULT NULL,
          `color` text,
          `material` text,
          `pattern` text,
          `size` text,
          `gender` text,
          `age_group` text,
          `adwords_labels` text,
          `custom_label_0` text,
          `custom_label_1` text,
          `custom_label_2` text,
          `custom_label_3` text,
          `custom_label_4` text,
          `feed_file` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          UNIQUE KEY `row_id` (`row_id`),
          KEY `title` (`title`),
          KEY `item_group_id` (`item_group_id`)
        ) $charset_collate;";

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

dbDelta( $sql );
} // End install ()
```

Please help.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at line:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$this->db_table} (
```

Here, `$this` is undefined.

Take it as a global variable.

For that, change `global $wpdb;` to `global $wpdb, $this;`

OR, check from where you should get the value of `db_table`, replace the appropriate variable/object in place of `$this->db_table`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_object($wpdb)) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/FILE NAME CLASS  OF YOUR FUNCTION get_charset_collate.php'; 
    $wpdb = new 'CLASS_NAME OF YOUR FUNCTION get_charset_collate';
}
```

and try to replace {$this->db_table} with {$wpdb->db_table} 
 Note: this is just idea to check the object variable.

Comment: sorry i did not get this

Answer (score 0):

You should be having something like below code in functions.php to use `$this`:

```
class SomeClass {
    var $db_table = 'my_table';
    ...
    function install() {
        global $wpdb;

        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$this->db_table} (
```

But you might not have similar code to get `$this->db_table` from `var $db_table`

So replace line 238 with

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE my_table (
```

to test whether it works